# Creating a NSSortDescriptor using a given locale

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sorting, localization

I'm using a NSFetchRequest to access a persistent store, into which I pass a NSSortDescriptor. The content to be sorted is in Norwegian, so I want it to **always** sort using the "nb-NO" locale, no matter the user preferences.

Right now I'm using the system locale to determine the sorting:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorting = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

What's the simplest/cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Select your project--> info ---> Set "Localization native development region" to "nb-NO". Dont forget to add the specific Localisaation files to your project. :)

If you want to sort according to your device language then below is the code

```
// Using fetch request 
-(NSFetchRequest*)returnFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest*)fetchRequest
{
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Your Entity Name" inManagedObjectContext:YOUR CONTEXT];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"title", nil)] ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    return fetchRequest;
}
```

Comment: The text is already localized. The problem is the way it is sorted, which varies with the locale. The three letters ÆØÅ come last (where they should be) with the "nb" locale, but not with the "en" locale.

Comment: Select your project--> info ---> Set "Localization native development region" to "nb-NO". Dont forget to add the specific Localisaation files to your project. :)

Comment: Not really what I want to accomplish. I just want to *sort* using that locale, the text is already in Norwegian. Tried it anyway, but the solution didn't work.

Comment: @Bruun Probably it's better to left it as it is. English men will search for å right under the a, I believe so.